# How to return the pointer in a pointer in a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I feel like this should be very easy, but I am unable to find an applicable question.

`X` is a `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Item> >`.

I have a function that accepts a `shared_ptr<Item>`

How do I get that inner pointer?  I can't just do `X ->`, and `X->get()` will return an `Item*`

Comment: why double shared_ptr???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with a normal pointer, you access a shared pointer's target by dereferencing it:

```
f(*X);
```